# How to rename multiple files in several folders?

Tags: unix, sed, find, exec, file-rename

I'd like to rename all files in several folders with filename containing '*file*' by '*doc*'. I've tried

```
find . -name "*file*" -exec mv {} `echo {} | sed "s/file/doc/"` \;
```

but got an error (see below).

```
~$ ls
my_file_1.txt  my_file_2.txt  my_file_3.txt

~$ find . -name "*file*"
./my_file_1.txt
./my_file_3.txt
./my_file_2.txt

~$ echo my_file_1.txt | sed "s/file/doc/"
my_doc_1.txt

~$ find . -name "*file*" -exec echo {} \;
./my_file_1.txt
./my_file_3.txt
./my_file_2.txt

~$ find . -name "*file*" -exec mv {} `echo {} | sed "s/file/doc/"` \;
mv: './my_file_1.txt' and './my_file_1.txt' are the same file
mv: './my_file_3.txt' and './my_file_3.txt' are the same file
mv: './my_file_2.txt' and './my_file_2.txt' are the same file
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a thousand ways to do it, I'd do it with Perl, something like this will work:

```
find files -type f -name "file*" | perl -ne 'chomp; $f=$_; $f=~s/\/file/\/doc/; `mv $_  $f`;'
```

- `-ne` process as inline script for each line input
- `chomp` clean a newline
- `$f` is new filename, same as old filename
- `s/\/file/\/doc/` replace "/file" with "/doc" in the new filename
- `mv $_  $f` rename the file by running an OS command with back ticks

Comment: Thanks. I tried (```find . -type f -name "*file*" | perl -ne 'chomp; $f=$_; $f=~s/\/file/\/doc/; `mv $_  $f`;'```) but it gives me the same error:```mv: './my_file_1.txt' and './my_file_1.txt' are the same file```

Comment: @TVG the answer explains what the regex is doing as an example, you need s/file/doc/ instead of s/\/file/\/doc/.

Comment: Thanks! ```find . -type f -name "*doc*" | perl -ne 'chomp; $f=$_; $f=~s/doc/file/; `mv $_  $f`;'``` works fine.

Comment: @TVG NP, glad you're unblocked. Would  you accept the answer if you're happy.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your solution is that the `echo {} | sed "s/file/doc/"` is executed before the rest of the `find` command. I tried to make a command demonstrating this:

```
find . -name "." -exec date \; -exec echo `date; sleep 5` \;
```

When the `date` commands aare executed from left to right, the dates would be equal. However the second `date` and the `sleep` are executed before `find` starts the first `date`.
Result:

```
Wed Aug 25 22:33:43 XXX 2021
Wed Aug 25 22:33:38 XXX 2021
```

The following solution is using `print0` and `xargs -0` for filenames with newlines. `xargs` will `echo` the `mv` command with two additional slashes.
The slashes will be found by the `sed` command, changing the target filename.
The result of `sed` is parsed by a new `bash` shell.

```
find . -name "*file1*"  -print0 2>/dev/null |
  xargs -0 -I {} echo mv '"{}"' //'"{}"' |
  sed -r 's#//(.*)file(.*)#\1doc\2#' |
  bash
```

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation! Have tried the command you propose and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have `rename` command. If it is `perl` based:

```sh
# -n is for testing, remove it for actual renaming
find -name '*file*' -exec rename -n 's/file/doc/' {} +
```

If it is not `perl` based, see if this works:

```sh
# remove --no-act --verbose for actual renaming
find -name '*file*' -exec rename --no-act --verbose 'file' 'doc' {} +
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried both commands but it gives me this error: `find: ‘rename’: No such file or directory`